Why did Herod not judge Jesus in Lk 23?
We read in Lk 23: 6-11( NIV).

On hearing this, Pilate asked if the man was a Galilean. When he learned that Jesus was under Herod’s jurisdiction, he sent him to Herod, who was also in Jerusalem at that time. When Herod saw Jesus, he was greatly pleased, because for a long time he had been wanting to see him. From what he had heard about him, he hoped to see him perform a sign of some sort. 9 He plied him with many questions, but Jesus gave him no answer. 10 The chief priests and the teachers of the law were standing there, vehemently accusing him. 11 Then Herod and his soldiers ridiculed and mocked him. Dressing him in an elegant robe, they sent him back to Pilate.

In flashback, we see in Lk 13, some Pharisees alerting Jesus of Herod's plot to kill him. But when Herod is supposed to judge and convict Jesus he recuses himself from doing so. In deed, the Pharisees had given the right information, going by the response of Jesus publicly  challenging Herod. Did Herod have a change of mind in the interim? My question is: Why did Herod not judge Jesus in Luke 23?

Jesus was more popular than the very unpopular Herod.  Thus, it is quite possible that Herod did not want to further antagonize the masses by condemning an obviously innocent man.  Thus, he sent Jesus back to Pilate to do the dirty work.  Note the comment in Matt 27:18 (about Pilate but would have also been true of Herod) - For he knew it was out of envy that they had handed Jesus over to him.

For starters, there's no guarantee that Herod actually wanted to kill Jesus though it's likely.
Ellicott's Commentary [1] presents three possibilities for Luke 13:31, 'for Herod will kill thee.':

The Pharisees’ had genuine concern: The Pharisees might have
reported what they actually knew, out of feelings more or less
friendly to Jesus.
The Pharisees’ lies: The Pharisees might have invented a false tale
in order to get rid of Jesus’ presence among them.
Herod actually gave the threat: The Pharisees might have been sent
by Herod to announce his purpose as a threat that he might be rid of
Jesus. This is supported by Jesus’ response, “Go tell that fox . .
.”.


Let's assume Herod gave the threat.
Superstition: Herod was somewhat of a lunatic, having killed John the Baptist, and imagining Jesus to be John reincarnated. This superstition might have prevented him from killing Jesus.

Matthew 14:3-5 and Mark 6:14-20 tell us that Herod hated John the
Baptist and consequently killed him and then was afraid that John had
been resurrected as Jesus Christ. [2]

Mark 6:14-20 NKJV says:

King Herod heard about this, for Jesus’ name had become well known.
Some were saying, “John the Baptist has been raised from the dead, and
that is why miraculous powers are at work in him.”
15 Others said, “He is Elijah.”
And still others claimed, “He is a prophet, like one of the prophets
of long ago.”
16 But when Herod heard this, he said, “John, whom I beheaded, has
been raised from the dead!”
17 For Herod himself had given orders to have John arrested, and he
had him bound and put in prison. He did this because of Herodias, his
brother Philip’s wife, whom he had married. 18 For John had been
saying to Herod, “It is not lawful for you to have your brother’s
wife.” 19 So Herodias nursed a grudge against John and wanted to kill
him. But she was not able to, 20 because Herod feared John and
protected him, knowing him to be a righteous and holy man. When Herod
heard John, he was greatly puzzled; yet he liked to listen to him.


Herod shrank from laying hands on him, though, for the memory of the
murdered friend of Jesus was a terrible one, we know, to the
superstitious tetrarch, and he dreaded being forced into a repetition
of the judicial murder of John the Baptist. [3]

Jesus was innocent:

When Pontius Pilate sent Jesus to Herod for trial because Jesus was
from Galilee, Herod was afraid of the chief priests and Sanhedrin.
Rather than seeking the truth from Jesus, Herod wanted him to perform
a miracle for his entertainment. Jesus would not comply. Herod and his
soldiers mocked Jesus. Then, instead of freeing this innocent man,
Herod sent him back to Pilate, who had the authority to have Jesus
crucified.
Herod's treachery improved his relationship with the chief priests and
Sanhedrin and started a friendship with Pilate from that day forward. [4]

We see Pilate say in Luke 23:14-16:

said to them, “You have brought this Man to me, as one who misleads
the people. And indeed, having examined Him in your presence, I have
found no fault in this Man concerning those things of which you accuse
Him; 15 no, neither did Herod, for I sent you back to him; and
indeed nothing deserving of death has been done by Him. 16 I will
therefore chastise Him and release Him”

Threat perception: If Herod did give the threat then it makes sense that Herod felt threatened by Jesus, as indicated by the warning. However, it may be that when Jesus was brought before him, Herod might have realized that Jesus was not the political threat he thought he was.
Herod didn't have the power to crucify Him. Jesus’ crucifixion was His destiny. Therefore, Jesus might have wanted to avoid being sentenced by Herod. Under Herod’s authority (as a Jewish ruler), Jesus would not have been crucified as that was a Roman practice. Instead he could have possibly been beheaded like John. That would not have fullfilled prophecy.

Psalm 22:16 NKJV
16 For dogs have surrounded Me; The congregation of the wicked has
enclosed Me.
They pierced My hands and My feet;





References:




[1]
Luke 13 Ellicott’s commentary for English readers. (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/luke/13.htm


[2]
Like the Master Ministries. (2024, June 26). Herod threatens to murder Christ - NeverThirsty. NeverThirsty. https://www.neverthirsty.org/bible-studies/ministry-perea/herod-threatens-to-murder-christ/


[3]
Luke 13 Pulpit commentary. (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/luke/13.htm


[4]
Zavada, J. (2019, February 10). Herod Antipas - Co-Conspirator in Jesus' death. Learn Religions. https://www.learnreligions.com/herod-antipas-co-conspirator-in-jesus-death-701060




Although Jesus was under the jurisdiction of Herod Antipas in the sense that the Galilee was his usual place of residence, the crime for which he was charged was not, in fact, under Herod's authority. Jesus had been accused of attempting to become the king of the Jews in Jerusalem, not in the Galilee.
Herod had apparently come to Jerusalem for the Passover festival, as was required for all pious Jews. Whether he himself was pious is not important; he needed to appear at the festival for political purposes. But he surely did not want to involve himself in Pilate's political problems - especially issues dealing with insurrection (vs. 19) and treason. He thus had no interest in bringing Jesus back to the Galilee for trial and punishment.
Conclusion: Although Herod Antipas had an interest in seeing Jesus, the Galilean was on trial for a crime against Roman authority in Jerusalem. It was not Herod's problem to deal with. Jesus resided in Herod's jurisdiction, but his alleged crime was committed in Jerusalem, where he entered the Temple to shouts of "Hosanna, Son of David."

2 Now after Jesus was born in Bethlehem of Judea in the days of Herod the king, behold, [a]wise men from the East came to Jerusalem, 2 saying, “Where is He who has been born King of the Jews? For we have seen His star in the East and have come to worship Him.”
3 When Herod the king heard this, he was troubled, and all Jerusalem with him ( Mtt 2) . Was Jerusalem not the HQ of Jews' king ?

John 19:27 :The Jews answered him, “We have a law, and according to our law He ought to die, because He made Himself the Son of God.” In Jn 18, thee Jews say that they are not mandated to put anyone to death. That power rested with Roman ruler. Hence the trial before Pilate. They also blackmail Pilate saying he would cease to be Caesar's friend if he let Jesus off, which gave him in. In sum, the charge initially levelled was blasphemy, which turned into attempt to reclaim autonomy for Israel, dethroning Caesar.
